# run laravel project without artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

i have an issue that i want to run my laravel project without cmd command php artisan serve , i want something like usually in php project localhost/projectName , when i do all the steps like changing hosts in System32/driver/etc/hosts 
and changing E:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf with all recommended option i restart wamp  but when i put on the url  projectname.dev the cercle above browser still Spins and nothing displays in the browser!!!!
someone has any idea

the configurations is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@ahssanstore.dev
    DocumentRoot "E:\wamp\www\AhssanStore\public"
    ServerName ahssanstore.dev
    ServerAlias www.ahssanstore.dev
    ErrorLog logs/ahssanstore.dev-error.log
    CustomLog logs/ahssanstore.dev-access.log common  
<Directory "E:\wamp\www\AhssanStore\public">
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
i add 127.0.0.1 ahssanstore.dev

and i restart wamp and after that i navigate to localhost/ahssanstore.dev

Comment: Please show the configs you have used.

Comment: i put the configs bro , you can see them now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows, you can try use [Laragon](https://laragon.org/).

Comment: is i should all time run it when i start windows or it automatically executed ?

Comment: You can set in the preference to run Laragon when Windows starts and Start all automatically. An [example](https://i.imgur.com/IUqLtn2.png) from the internet.

Answer (score 1):

For those that have an Ubuntu Dev Server (with the possibility of other projects in your /var/www) I did the following to make it work.

Rename your-app/server.php to your-app/index.php
Copy .htaccess from your-app/public/ to your-app/

PS: If anyone knows that this creates some problems down the line please advice.

Done

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, **servername**: '**projectname.dev**' doesn't work (I'm used to meet like this). Try changing '**projectname.me**' instead '**project.dev**'.

For **VirtualHost configuration**, you only need to **set two lines**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "E:\wamp\www\AhssanStore\public"
     ServerName ahssanstore.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Just Sharing my knowledge. Hope it also works!